# Insert image into HTML page using absolute path

Tags: html

I'm given a task to insert an image to an index2 HTML page using absolute path, however, I'm getting this error " Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND." if I use this path "images/baby-01.jpg", but If I use the relative path given below, I'm able to load the image.

```
<img src="/Users/gill/Downloads/Lab1/lab1-part2-images/abs-path/images/baby-01.jpg" alt="baby 01"/>"
```

Image path

```
/Users/gill/Downloads/Lab1/lab1-part2-images/abs-path/images/baby-01.jpg
```

The path of the page I'm trying to insert the image into.

```
/Users/gill/Downloads/Lab1/lab1-part2-images/abs-path/local news/index2.html
```

Answer (score 1):

The absolute path has to be the absolute **URL** path and not the absolute **filesystem** path.

The root of the path is the directory the web server is configured to treat as a root, not the file system that the web server is installed on (otherwise, anyone could download any file from any computer running a web server).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Flask (or other web server serving stuff) and the app can't find your image (even though you know it exists) you can use a symbolic link to trick Flask to do what you want.

Here is the link: https://www.howtogeek.com/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/
But basically, a symbolic link is a shortcut that fools programs into thinking its the actual file/directory. For this application, I recommend using:

`mkdir /D Link Target`

to link a directory. Link is the "fake directory" that should be in your project folder (where main.py is), and target is the directory that you want to copy (C://Users/Anon/QuestionablePics, for example). Remember to use quotes if the directory has a space, or use them anyway idc.